# Xcode - How to change application/project name : what do I need to to update and check?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, compiler-construction

Using Xcode 4.2, if I want to change my application/project name (including the name of the project folder and subfolder that are auto created by Xcode), what are the different items I need to update to make the whole thing compile and work again like a charm ?

I have noticed that I have to change the pch acces path, the bundle identifier, ... but I'm afraid of missing something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An advice : **NEVER** change the name of your project without having saved the whole thing before. Even if XCode has a feature that helps to do this, using it may destroy all your hard work to organise your project, letting many many dirty things everywhere, not changing everything that needs to be changed, it's just awfull. I've tried this some days ago on a just simple project, letting XCode change the main things, but it has let so many things unchanged, or changed things without updating links, so I've had to rebuild a new project from the beginning to make it compile again.

Answer (score 25):

It's really easy in Xcode 4. Simply double click (slowly) on your project name in the Navigator (the bar on the left). When you change the name of your project, Xcode will ask you to confirm which files to change (generally, it will be all of the ones necessary).

Alternately, if you simply want to change the name of your bundle (the name of your app as it appears in a users' home screen), you can just change your "Bundle Display Name" in your app plist.

Comment: That will also change my folder names ?

Comment: SLOWLY is so important.  It was not working for me until SLOWLY.

Comment: When I do this, I get fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /Volumes/Multimedia)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to change the App name, select the project in xcode, select the app in TARGETS > YourAppOldName. Press enter, rename the OldName. Save, compile. thats all!

Answer (score 0):

Change the config.xml from the main www directory

Here is the Name you want to change 
    
        here is description of your application
    
 
       My team
 
Now rebuild app with CLI

phonegap build ios, phonegap install ios or phonegap run ios